# htaccess: redirect only .html files to website root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've recently upgraded a static site to a CMS and I'd like to redirect all the html files of the old site to the site's root (http://www.url.com), without affecting the CMS' PHP.

Current htaccess looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Obviously whatever new rules I add mustn't conflict with this.

I'd like old files (url.com/page.html) to redirect to url.com.

I've tried a few things after searching but nothing works. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add these rules **before** your CMS rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# check that the request isn't for a legitimate existing resource
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# redirect the .html request to the site root
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ / [L,R=301]
```