# Redirecting all .html files to root folder using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**My `.htaccess` file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^pharmacy/?(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/swift-mailer/lib/classes/$1 [L]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

After [reading this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955867/htaccess-redirect-only-html-files-to-website-root) I tried adding `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ / [L,R=301]` after `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` which redirects html files to root folder but other URL stops working.

**PS**: I am not used to with .htaccess files.

Comment: put it above rewriteCond

Comment: @splash58 you mean above `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` code?

Comment: Yes, because Cond affects only 1st Rule

Comment: @splash58 worked well. Thanks a ton :) Can you write the same in answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Good luck, PankitKapadia! :)

Comment: i've created the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put new RewriteRule before RewriteConds because it does not need any condition for redirect.

Moreover, you save working old redirect rules. RewriteCond affects only 1st RewriteRule after it. Placing new RewriteRule after RewriteConds make old RewriteRule be acheived in all cases without any restriction.

So, the fragment of your htaccess should look like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the root redirect code above the WordPress code like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^pharmacy/?(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/swift-mailer/lib/classes/$1 [L]

    # This will check that the .html is not a true file
    # and if so, redirect to root
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ / [L,R=302]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note, use `R=302` (temporary redirect) until you are satisfied with your redirects. Otherwise, you might have 'permanent' redirects to inadvertent places.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand clearly, your .htaccess now looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pharmacy/?(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/swift-mailer/lib/classes/$1 [L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

As RewriteCond rules only affect one RewrtieRule below them, this rule

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

now applies to every request. Simply change your .htaccess to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pharmacy/?(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/swift-mailer/lib/classes/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ / [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```